# Sending soap request with an xml as dime attachment

Tags: php, soap

I've got the following issue:
I have to create a soap client and server communication. I am implementing the client part and using php. This communication between the server and the client has 4 steps. One of these step i have to send a soap request to the server with an xml, as a dime attachment.

The problem is:
I couldn't figure out how to create a soap request with dime attachment.
I've found that Pear has a `Net_Dime` package, but i didn't found any example or tutorial how to use it.

Any advice warmly welcome.

Comment: DIME is an outdated attachments format. Consider using MTOM instead for newly created services.

Comment: me too. I also want to create a SOAP request with DIME attachment. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you still need this answer? Do you have an WSDL? Do you have test service? Soap method name? Anything?